# From pure Hibernate to JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Currently I am using pure hibernate and I'm pretty happy with it, except casting on calls like `session.get/list` and others, but that is not a big deal...

What benefits will I gain with `JPA` except better portability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe better tooling, and vendor support. Easier deployment on compliant application servers, too. But you'll loose Hibernate-specific features, like extended query syntax in HQL. After all, JPA's features are a subset of Hibernate's.